# What exactly are the "specific concerns" that are acceptable in the Proofreading closure?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons

I have read [What the "proofreading" close reason is for](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4515/what-the-proofreading-close-reason-is-for).

But, I'm still not 100% clear what we mean by "specific concerns."

Are we saying that the following would be acceptable:

> Is this sentence grammatically correct:
>
> > Example sentence
>
> I believe that the use of xyz phrase is not appropriate here because ...

vs.

> Is this sentence grammatically correct:
>
> > Example sentence

(with no point of specific concern noted ...)

---

I frequently see both types of questions tagged as proofreading.  And, I'm just as guilty as the next guy for tagging and/or going along with the tags of others.  I want to make certain that I'm not being overly harsh in using these tags.

Comment: Yes, the first question is fine (assuming there are no other problems with it), whereas the second should be closed as proofreading.

Comment: And both also really should read "Is this sentence grammatical?"

Comment: @kitfox while I don't disagree that grammatical should be preferred due to its lack of assigning value. I think the other is fairly common usage (even on this site).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I tried to address this in [What the "proofreading" close reason is for](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4515/what-the-proofreading-close-reason-is-for), but I may have been too long-winded for my own good. tl;dr version: If the questioner is clearly more interested in *getting* an answer than in *understanding* the answer (i.e., if it smells suspiciously like a "do my homework for me" question), I usually vote to close as Proofreading. If the question shows a good faith effort to understand what the problem might be, I usually let it slide.

For your examples, I'd vote to close the second one and keep the first one open.

Comment: That's a good way of distinguishing *potentially* proofreading questions. Personally, I would have said [this question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/90463/), for example, is "proofreading", but people do tend to go for General Reference if OP asks *"Is this grammatical?"*, only picking Proofreading when the OP asks *"Are there any errors?"*